# Subset a grouped data frame based on range of row position

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, datatable

I have a grouped data frame and I wish to keep for each group (name) the rows in a given range .For ex, between 2nd and 3rd position.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), x = 1:9)
df
  name x
1    a 1
2    a 2
3    a 3
4    b 4
5    b 5
6    c 6
7    c 7
8    c 8
```

Here I want an output like this

```
  name x
1    a 2
2    a 3
3    b 5
4    c 7
5    c 8
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `group_by` `name`, then `slice` from index `2:3`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  slice(2:3)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   name [3]
  name      x
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 a         3
3 b         5
4 c         7
5 c         8
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is using `dplyr::slice(2:3)`